# Filling an empty Dataframe without defining dimensions

Tags: r

I am curious if there is a way to fill in an empty data frame without having to define the dimensions. This might be useful for me in cases where I don't know how large the end result is going to be.

```
foo <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:5){
  foo[, i] <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
}
```

this gives the error
`Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, , i, value = c(1L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 6L,  :
  replacement has 10 rows, data has 0`

I know you can define the dimensions and it will work with the following, but I am wondering if there is an alternative where you don't have to do this.

```
foo <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 0))
```

Comment: You can do this with a `list` i.e. `foo <- list()'
for(i in 1:5) foo[[i]] <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)`  It is recommended to initialize the list with preferred length for efficiency.  A `data.frame` is a list with elements of equal length and holding some attributes

Comment: It is generally not very efficient to dynamically fill (grow) a `data.frame` of unspecified dimensions in a loop. You're trying very hard to do something that you generally should avoid doing in R. Can you provide more details as to what you're ultimately trying to do?

Comment: you can bind your result everytime to the dataframe if you dont want to define the size in advance with cbind or rbind

Comment: @R.Prost I believe only `rbind` will work, not `cbind`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I don't have a particular example that I am working with. What I am working on is a simulation so I know how big I want the `data.frame` to be. I was just asking for general knowledge. It is good to know that it is possible, but not generally a good practice. I did not know this.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be

```
foo <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:5) foo <- rbind(foo, sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

which is equivalent to

```
for (i in 1:5) foo[i,] <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
```

Then, transposing it, you can get what you want, i.e.

```
> t(foo)
      1 2 3 4 5
X.1   8 6 8 1 9
X.2   4 3 4 3 1
X.3   6 2 1 3 7
X.4  10 7 8 4 1
X.5   3 4 6 3 1
X.6   4 4 5 4 2
X.7   9 5 5 3 8
X.8   9 1 4 7 1
X.9   7 4 4 5 9
X.10  5 4 2 2 6
```

(As indicated, whenever feasible, you probably want to define the size and structure of `foo` as it makes the code much more efficient).